# How to install lib32-alsa-plugins-1.2.2-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package, wine, libalsa

I downloaded file from https://archlinux.org/packages/multilib/x86_64/lib32-alsa-plugins/
How command i need to use that installing this package?

Answer (score 0):

you have to unzip the file and install it with pacman -U

Comment: lib32-alsa-plugins-1.2.2-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' is not a Debia
n format archive